# Display Uploaded PDF files

Tags: angularjs

> i'm trying to display the uploaded PDF Files using pdf-viewer but it
>   is displaying in base64 format so i'm trying image tag but it is not
>   displaying for both below is my code
>
> using img tag

```
<li ng-repeat="d in data track by $index">
    <img data-ng-src="{{d}}"  data-err-src="">
</li>
```

> using pdf-viewer tag

```
<li ng-repeat="d in data track by $index">
    <pdf-viewer ngf-src="file">{{d}}</pdf-viewer>
</li>
```

> here i'm uploading multiple pdf files to array and iterating using
>   ng-repeat

//Controller Code

```
app.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope,$rootScope,getFactory) { 
    imageIsLoaded(); 
    function imageIsLoaded() { 
        $scope.data=getFactory.getData("array"); 
        console.log($scope.data); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: add your `data` structure in question also.

Comment: app.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope,$rootScope,getFactory) {
 imageIsLoaded();
  function imageIsLoaded() {
    $scope.data=getFactory.getData("array");
 console.log($scope.data);
}
});